# Exception nullptr thrown for Reverse Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, nullpointerexception, linked-list

[image]   This is the output I am getting as seen above.
I am new to Linked Lists. I am here creating a linked list and adding node and attempting to reverse and print the list.

Here is my code:

```
//this is my PracImplement header file
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node { 

public:
Node();
~Node();
int data;
Node* next;
};

class PracNImplement
{
public:
PracNImplement();
~PracNImplement();

void addNode(int);
void reverseList();
void printList();
void testList();
private:
Node* top = NULL;
};

//this is my PracImplement cpp file
#include "PracNImplement.h"
using namespace std;

Node::Node() {
//default constructor
}
Node::~Node() {}
PracNImplement::PracNImplement()
{
//default constructor
top = NULL;
}


PracNImplement::~PracNImplement()
{
// destructor
}

void PracNImplement::addNode(int val) {
Node* temp = new Node(); //creating a new node
temp->data = val;
temp->next = NULL;
if (top == NULL) {
    top = temp; //checking the head or else feel with data(val)
}
else {
    Node* temp1 = top;
    while (temp1->next != NULL){
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp;
    }   
}
}

void PracNImplement::reverseList() {
Node* n1 = top;
Node* n2 = NULL;
Node* n3 = NULL;
while (n1 != NULL) {
    top = n1;
    n2 = n1->next;
    n1->next = n3;
    n3 = n1;
    n1 = n2;
}

}

void PracNImplement::printList() {
Node* temp = top;
while (temp != NULL) {
    cout << temp->data << endl;
    temp=temp->next;
}
cout << endl;
}


//This is my test function
int main(){
PracNImplement* ttl = new PracNImplement();
ttl->addNode(20);
ttl->addNode(21);
ttl->addNode(22);
ttl->addNode(23);
ttl->addNode(24);
ttl->addNode(25);
cout << "The current list has the following items: " << endl;
ttl->printList();
ttl->reverseList();
cout << "This is the reversed list items: " << endl;
ttl->printList();
delete ttl;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio as my IDE. It throws error as

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.
temp was nullptr.
```

Could someone please reveal what is wrong here?

Comment: `Node* temp = NULL; //creating a new node` No, it doesn't create a new `Node`.

Comment: @songyuanyao but that is I am declaring a Node pointer named temp which is initialized to NULL

Comment: You didn't construct `Node`, `temp` is a null pointer, then `temp->data` won't work.

Comment: Yah. "Node* temp = nullptr;  temp->data = val;" - so what do you think will happen when you dereference a null pointer?

Comment: @songyuanyao I have added the constructor, but still the same.

Comment: The constructor of `Node` won't be called, until you write `Node* temp = new Node;`.

Comment: @songyuanyao I have made the necessary changes, if you can see now I have a new thing. The add node section is only adding 20 and not the other nodes; as a result I am getting result of original list to be 20 and reversed to be 20 ... I debugged and checked that other elements are not getting added. However it is going through the function that addnode that many times when called.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What do you think about my above comment. Changes made as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

After the fixes made above we just need to change the the addNode function rather copy paste. It should be :

```
void PracNImplement::addNode(int val) {
Node* temp = new Node(); //creating a new node
temp->data = val;
temp->next = NULL;
if (top == NULL) {
    top = temp; //checking the head or else feel with data(val)
}
else {
    Node* temp1 = top;
    while (temp1->next != NULL){
        temp1 = temp1->next;

    }   
    temp1->next = temp;
}
}
```

That shall fix it. Thanks for all the help.